# Nonpiecewise Jump Discontinuity

Tags: limits, continuity, piecewise-continuity

I need to find an equation that is **NOT** piecewise such that
f(0)=0,
the limit of f(x) as x approaches 0 from the positive side = 1/2,
and the limit of f(x) as x approaches 0 from the negative side = -1/2.
Are there any equations in which a jump discontinuity naturally occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about $\frac{1}{2} \left( \left\lfloor \frac{x}{|x|+1} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{-x}{|-x|+1} \right\rfloor \right)$?  (Stolen shamelessly from the [obvious Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).), where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is notation for the floor function.